# Error messages while setting up Event Calendars using Calendar and Views modules

Tags: civievent, drupal, drupal-views, calendar

Trying to set up some calendars on my website and running into trouble with both my theme screwing up the display and these error messages showing:

Notice: Undefined offset: 27 in calendar_plugin_row_civicrm->render() (line 135 of /home/***/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/drupal/modules/views/plugins/calendar_plugin_row_civicrm.inc).

Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$start_date in calendar_plugin_row_civicrm->render() (line 156 of /home/***/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/drupal/modules/views/plugins/calendar_plugin_row_civicrm.inc).

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in calendar_plugin_style->render() (line 305 of /home/***/public_html/sites/all/modules/calendar/includes/calendar_plugin_style.inc).

I am using the CiviCRM Events View that was installed by one of the involved modules. The events DO show on the calendar, and I CAN click on them to get to the event page. In other words, things appear to be working, but I can't get rid of these error messages showing up on the page.

Error is only showing up on current month, January. Ah - if i filter out all events prior to today's date, there are no error messages. So temporary fix, but I do want to be able to scroll back through the months and see past events.

Civicrm 4.6.11
Drupal  7.41

Would appreciate any suggestions. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Just update the calendar module to latest version, it will fix the issue.

Comment: I am using the latest version from here: 
https://www.drupal.org/project/calendar

Comment: Check, there may be database update for calendar module.

sitename/update.php

Also check the date module weather it's updated or not.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't get a solution via the module you can try the [CiviCRM Entities module](http://www.drupal.org/project/civicrm_entity) (2.x version)  and the Calendar module then in Views you should find that you can use "Add from template" and there is a template for Civi Event.

Comment: Thanks, I do have that module and did try adding from template, but still get errors: Notice: Undefined index: path in calendar_plugin_row->render() (line 401 of /home/***/public_html/sites/all/modules/calendar/includes/calendar_plugin_row.inc).

Answer (score 0):

This may not have anything to do with CiviCRM. I am seeing a similar problem with a site that doesn't use CiviCRM. Here are some of the errors I see:

Notice: Undefined property: calendar_plugin_row::$date_argument in calendar_plugin_row->render() (line 365 of /srv/bindings/.../code/sites/all/modules/calendar/includes/calendar_plugin_row.inc).
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in calendar_plugin_row->render() (line 365 of /srv/bindings/.../code/sites/all/modules/calendar/includes/calendar_plugin_row.inc).
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in calendar_plugin_row->render() (line 365 of /srv/bindings/.../code/sites/all/modules/calendar/includes/calendar_plugin_row.inc).
Notice: Undefined property: calendar_plugin_row::$date_fields in calendar_plugin_row->render() (line 375 of /srv/bindings/.../code/sites/all/modules/calendar/includes/calendar_plugin_row.inc).

Answer (score 0):

These are notices, not errors, and are generally harmless. You should configure Drupal to hide them in yoursite.org/admin/config/development/logging.